# How to print list object in jsp usin forEach loop?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

Given this [jsp page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMNEG.png) and [this controller code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ws84a.png), when I tried printing the object directly it gives me the output:

```
[User [id=1, firstName=Ishwar, lastName=Sonar, emailId=ishwarsonar95@gmail.com`]]
```

But when I use forEach to print the single data of the object, it gives me the error below:

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).

```
The class 'com.suraj.springbootdemo.entity.User' does not have the property 'firstName'.
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'com.suraj.springbootdemo.entity.User' does not have the property 'firstName'.
```

Comment: Can you share your code with us?

Comment: I have linked code images to my question, Your help would be appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: That image doesn't compile. Please don't post text as image, but rather provide the text itself.

Answer (score 0):

When printing the user inside the `forEach`, you are trying to access the `firstName` property. JSP expression language does not work on properties, only on getter/setter methods (e.g. `getFirstName()`). If you don't have a getter yet, you need to create one in your `User` class:

```java
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
```

And then you can access it inside the JSP code using:

```html
<td>${u.getFirstName()}</td>
```

Comment: Tysm for your answer. I forgot to generate the getters and setters. I'll do it now!

Comment: I'd also like to suggest you improve your question, by placing the code as text with the appropriate formatting instead of images, so it can be helpful to other users running into the same issue later.

Comment: I do understand and will look after it, as I was not able to edit my ques it by ctrl+K, it is not allowing me to do so! this was my first question in sof.